# Change style in leaflet easybutton.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using the leaflet plugin easybutton.js I have added 2 buttons, but I would like to change the background color of them at different points but I am can't seem to fully get there. I can change the background color when adding them but the effect only takes when clicked and I would also like to be able to change the background color at different points.

https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton

The buttons are added like so

```
L.easyButton('<img src="img/myimage.jpg">', function(btn, map){
 btn.button.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    var destination = [newlat, newlng];
    map.setView(destination);
}).addTo(map);

L.easyButton('<img src="img/myimage2.jpg">', function(btn, map){
    btn.button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    var destination = [52.450439,-1.729660];
    map.setView(destination);
}).addTo(map);
```

As you can see, this changes the background color but only when clicked and if I want to change any of these later how do I do it? Do I have to give them an id or something?

Comment: Looks like you could save the `btn` value in a global and re-run the `btn.button.style.backgroundColor` assignment elsewhere. Did you try this?

Comment: not sure what you mean?

Comment: I've added an answer with some suggested code.

Answer (score 1):

Save the button objects in global variables so you can use them later....

```
var btn1;
var btn2;    
L.easyButton('<img src="img/myimage.jpg">', function(btn, map){
 btn1 = btn;
 btn.button.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    var destination = [newlat, newlng];
    map.setView(destination);
}).addTo(map);

L.easyButton('<img src="img/myimage2.jpg">', function(btn, map){
    btn2 = btn;
    btn.button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    var destination = [52.450439,-1.729660];
    map.setView(destination);
}).addTo(map);
```

Somewhere else in your code when you want to programmatically change the colours::

```
btn1.button.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
btn2.button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```